# Coffeescript + Express.js : cannot call method 'sliced' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, slice

I'm making my first app in express.js and coffeescript. The code is at:
https://github.com/findjashua/contactlist

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
/Users/jashua/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/helpers.js:216
  codeLine = codeLine.slice(0, start) + colorize(codeLine.slice(start, end
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined
  at Object.exports.prettyErrorMessage (/Users/jashua/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/helpers.js:216:27)
  at compileScript (/Users/jashua/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:199:25)
  at /Users/jashua/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:143:18
  at fs.js:266:14
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with contacts.coffee, but can't think of anything. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like an error in coffeescript internals. are you running the latest version?

Comment: yep, latest versions of coffeescript(1.6.3) and express(3.3.4). It runs fine with a simple hello world (when I comment out calls to contacts.coffee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the parens for `new ContactModel(`.

```
  exports.addContact = (req, res) ->
contact = new ContactModel(
    name: req.body.name
    phone: req.body.phone
contact.save((err) ->
    if not err
        console.log('created')
        res.send(contact)
    else
        res.send(error)
)
```

My tip: forget all these parens. Part of the nice thing about coffeescript is you can use indentation and not have big chains of floating closing delimiters like the close parens in your source. Just do:

```
someFunction (arg1, arg2) ->
  body of nested function
```

Comment: thanks man! Any idea why coffeescript didn't just tell me it was a paren issue?